# Managing Django Factories

Tags: python, django, testing

Would there be an issue with including a factory in the model class itself? I know it's valid python but I'm not sure it would break anything in Django. My initial testing shows it works fine, but I haven't seen examples online doing it this way.

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    ....
    class Factory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it won't break anything, but in my opinion, keeping factories together with models doesn't look good. I think it's cleaner to split them and put factories closer to tests rather than the models.